# L is injective if and only if Ker L = $\{0_V\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show the following proposition

Proposition

Let $L:V\to W$ be a linear transformation

L is injective $\Leftarrow \Rightarrow$ $Ker L =$ $\{0_V\}$

proof:

$\Rightarrow$

Suppose that L is injective, this implies that

If L(u) = L(v) Then u = v

This is equivalent to

If L(u) - L(v) = $0_W$ Then u = v

This is equivalent to

If L(u - v) = $0_W$ Then u - v = $0_V$

This is equivalent to

If u - v $\in$ Ker L Then u - v = $0_V$

therefore Ker L = $\{0_V\}$

Now the other side

$\Leftarrow$

Suppose that Ker L = {$0_V$}

u,t $\in$ Ker L this implies that

L(u) = $0_W$

L(t) = $0_W$

So L(u) = L(t)

By hypothesis u = $0_V$ and t = $0_V$

So u = t

therefore L is injective

I think $\Rightarrow$ is correct but I am not sure about $\Leftarrow$

Is correct my proof?

Comment: For $\Longrightarrow$ direction, I would say that $L(v) = L(0)$ implies that $v=0$ to shorten the proof. For the other direction, note that $L(v) = L(w)$ implies that $L(v-w) = 0$, but if the kernel is just zero, it means that $v-w =0$, i.e. $v = w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second direction, assume that Ker$(L)$ is $0_V$ and consider $u,t\in V$ with $Lu=Lt$. Subtracting $Lt$ to the other side gives $Lu-Lt=0\implies L(u-t)=0$ by linearity of $L$. This implies that $u-t$ is an element of Ker$(L)$ but we assumed that was $0_V$ so $u-t=\vec{0}$ but this means that $u=t$, which makes $L$ injective since $u$ and $t$ were arbitrary.